# Determining support of variable in bivariate change of variables

Tags: probability

For random variable $X_1$, $X_2$ ~ iid Exp(1), $Z=X_1-X_2$ I tried to figure out PDF of $X_1|Z$.

With change of variable $X_1=Y$ and  $X_2=Y-Z$, I got joint PDF,

$$f_{Y,Z}(y,z)=e^{z-2y}I_{y>0, z<y}$$
$$f_Z(z)= \int^{\infty}_{z}f_{Y,Z}(y,z)dy=0.5e^{-z}$$

Now my question is how do I determine the $\text{supp}(Z)$. Clearly, it's not $(-\infty,\infty)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The joint pdf is right but for the pdf of $Z$ you have two ranges to treat separately, since we must have both $0\lt y$ and $z\lt y$:

If $z\lt 0,\;$ then

\begin{align}
f_Z(z) &= \int_{0}^{\infty}f_{Y,Z}(y,z)dy = \left[ -\dfrac{1}{2}e^{z-2y} \right]_{0}^{\infty} = \dfrac{1}{2}e^{z}.
\end{align}

If $z\geq 0,\;$ then

\begin{align}
f_Z(z) &= \int_{z}^{\infty}f_{Y,Z}(y,z)dy = \left[ -\dfrac{1}{2}e^{z-2y} \right]_{z}^{\infty} = \dfrac{1}{2}e^{-z}.
\end{align}

These could be combined as:

$$f_Z(z)  = \dfrac{1}{2}e^{-|z|}, \quad\forall\; z\in \mathbb{R}.$$

And, yes, the support of $Z$ is $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Good point. I ,too, actually thought the support is R, but with my marginal pdf, it didn't make sense.

Comment: @user276440 Yes, often, figuring out the correct ranges is the trickiest part of doing change-of-variables like these.